# Comparing keys of dictionary to add to the value - Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to compare keys from a dictionary so that if there are multiple keys with a different values I can add those different values to that one key. For example say we have dict{'a':'b','b':'c','c':'d'} and I add {'a':'c'} I am wondering how I can change the dictionary so that it is now dict{'a':'bc','b':'c','c':'d'}

Answer (score 0):

To make this whole process work, you really should try writing some code. Here's some inspiration to get you started.

First, you need to be able to iterate through a Python dict and get all the keys and values in turn:

```
for key, value in new_dict.items():
```

Okay, that's pretty useful.

Next, we need a way to know if the new key is going to be in the old dict or not. We've got two ways to do that here:

```
for key, value in new_dict.items():
   if key in old_dict:
       write some code that goes here
   else:
       write some alternate code here for when key isn't in the dict
```

Alternately, we can do this:

```
for key, value in new_dict.items():
   old_dict_key_val = old_dict.get(key)
   if old_dict_key_val is not None:
       write some code that goes here
   else:
       write some alternate code here for when key isn't in the dict
```

For all intents and purposes, those are pretty much equivalent. This should be enough to get you started! After that, you can come back here with specific questions if you get stuck.

Good luck writing some code yourself to solve this issue!

Answer (score 0):

A little bit unconventional using try/except, but very compact and Pythonic.

```
big_dict = {'a':'b','b':'c','c':'d'}
little_dict = {'a':'c'}

for key, value in little_dict.items():
    try:
        big_dict[key] += value
    except KeyError:
        big_dict[key] = value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the neat function `merge_with` from the package toolz (https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

The function works in the following way: you take as arguments (1) a function which will work on the values from different dicts with the same key, and (2) the dicts you want to merge.

```
from toolz import merge_with

d1 = {'a':'i','b':'j'}
d2 = {'a':'k'}

def conc(a):
    return ''.join(a)

a = merge_with(conc,d1,d2)

>>> {'a': 'ik', 'b': 'j'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(str)
d.update({'a': 'b','b': 'c','c': 'd'})
print(d)
// defaultdict(<type 'str'>, {'a': 'b', 'b': 'c', 'c': 'd'})

d.update({'a': 'c'})
print(d)
// defaultdict(<type 'str'>, {'a': 'bc', 'b': 'c', 'c': 'd'})
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured out a solution for my problem thanks for the reply 
what I did was this sorry for any confusion about my question. This allowed me to check if the key was in the dictionary and if so I could add the values of that key together

```
for x in range(len(word)) 
    key = word[x] 
    if key in dict:
       dict[word[x]] = [word[x+1] + dict[word[x]] 
    else:
        dict[word[x] = word[x+1]
```